# How to write OnClick="return Foo()" in jquery

Tags: jquery

How do I write OnClick="return Foo()" in jquery to prevent the button from submitting while the function is not yet finished. TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach a handler to the `click` event for your target element, pass your handler the event object as a parameter, and call `preventDefault()` on the event within your handler. Like so:

```
$('#mydiv').click(function(e) {
  // do something
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

For more information see [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and the [event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) at the jQuery API.

Answer (score 1):

It will not submit until function has finished executing anyway. If you want to prevent the button from submitting just return false from Foo().

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery docs for [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/). Something like this perhaps?

```
$('#buttonid').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    Foo();
});
```

Keep in mind that the click event is triggered for submit buttons/inputs even when selected through a keyboard event.

jQuery has excellent documentation. Take some time to read through it and you'll get where you want faster than guess work.